# How to start a Chromium extension directly from a shortcut or command in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I want to run "Chat for Google" (Use the Chat for Google extension to connect and communicate.)  Chrome/Chromium extension directly using a command or short cut in Ubuntu. (I know how to create desktop short cut for Chrome/Chromium web apps, but that is not possible with this extension.)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd

Comment: so basically you want to shortcut that app to your desktop but you are not being able to do so?

Comment: Yes, I need a desktop short cut or a command to run this.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Windows, maybe it also works for you on Linux:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1" --kiosk --app-id="idoftheapp" --app=chrome-extension://"extension name url"
```

For example:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1" --kiosk --app-id=lkcngchfhbcfncpnoejcbncjnahgkbpo --app=chrome-extension://mefgmmbdailogpfhfblcnnjfmnpnmdfa/reader.html
```

Answer (score 0):

When mighty Captain Obvious stroke me reading this, out of curiosity I tried to call the extension ID as given by the web store to see what would happen:

"/usr/bin/chromium --profile-directory=Default --app-id=nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd"

Result: It actually calls the Hangouts extension yet it brings up just a child menu of configuration menu. This one closes when leaving via OK/Cancel, so the princess is in another castle.

Though I wonder if there could be any ID pointing on the right spot, calling the main extension?